# Sending UTF 8 from iOS to PHP via POST

Tags: php, ios, utf-8, base64, nsurlrequest

So I have been doing some research into getting my UTF8 to print correctly.  And I found a good example of my problem here:
[UTF8 Encoding problem - With good examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095899/utf8-encoding-problem-with-good-examples)'

So I setup the test myself but with this result:   (PHP)

```
echo "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">";
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_http_output("UTF-8");
mb_http_input("UTF-8");

$textEnc = _POST["text"];
$text = cc_decode($textEnc);
echo 'Original : ', $text."<br />";
$enc = mb_detect_encoding($text, "UTF-8,ISO-8859-1");

echo 'Detected encoding '.$enc."<br />";

echo 'Fixed result: '.iconv($enc, "UTF-8", $text)."<br />";
```

Result:   (Result HTML)

```
Original : „Å≤
Detected encoding UTF-8
Fixed result: „Å≤
```

I was expecting a japanese character ひ

The code I am using to create the request looks like: (Obj C)

```
NSString* cCode = B64EncodeString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",data->Text()]);
NSString* connectURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", SERVER_ADDRESS, @"users/test.php"];

NSString* mPostArgs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text=%@", cCode];

NSMutableURLRequest* theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:mTimeoutInSeconds];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[theRequest setValue:@"UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"accept-charset"];

if(mPostArgs != nil) {

    NSData* myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [mPostArgs UTF8String] length: [mPostArgs length]];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
}

// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
NSURLConnection* theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Comment: You really don't need to do that much. What do you get for a simple `bin2hex($_POST['text'])`?

Comment: I didn't know about bin2hex, thank you, very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString* cCode = B64EncodeString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",data->Text()]);
```

took the string incorrectly, I changed it to not re-create the NSString

```
NSString* cCode = B64EncodeRaw((const uint8_t*)data->Text(), strlen(data->Text()));
```