# How to make php work with utf-8 strings?

Tags: php, utf-8

<strike>Obviously, this won't work:</strike>

```
<?php
$newstring = "测试";
echo $newstring;
?>
```

How do you make it work with `utf-8` strings?

**EDIT:**

I just realized that the online file editor of webmin does NOT automatically save files as `utf-8` encoded, and after uploading a new file onto my server everything works all right, the best part is, that online file editor doesn't seem to even support any `utf-8` encoded files.

Comment: not a php issue, you would rather set the charset in your HTML head, using `<meta charset="utf-8">`. However, if you're getting your string through mysql, you should be sure to set the mysql encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: You can reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095899/utf8-encoding-problem-with-good-examples

Answer (score 2):

"Obviously" is a weird choice of words, since this *does* in fact work just fine, if:

1. The source code is ASCII compatible so PHP can interpret it.
2. The source code and thereby the string is saved in the same encoding that the reading party is going to interpret it in.

So, if you save this file in UTF-8 (which is ASCII compatible) and open it in a browser, the browser needs to interpret the page as UTF-8. You can do this by setting an appropriate HTTP header. If you're going to execute this script on the command line, the terminal will have to be able to interpret UTF-8 and be able to display it.

String literals in PHP are raw byte arrays, they're not being interpreted by PHP. They can be anything you want. They can be binary data like images, as long as you can get your text editor to save the file correctly. They're only interpreted as text by the party that's trying to display the characters on screen. See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for excruciating in-depth details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your source code in UTF-8 encoding

Also, you could add this to your source code

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this into your `php.ini` file:

```
default_charset = "utf-8";
```

If not you will have to set the headers on the top on every single file like:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Also take a look on your database settings if you save these strings there.