# PHP json_encode & utf8_encode

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I have an array to json encode. Json error gives utf8 error. Then I tried to utf8ize the array, but it makes my good utf8 texts to wrong: "*láthatod a fényképeiket*" -> "*lÃ¡thatod a fÃ©nykÃ©peiket*". I tried to utf8ize only not utf8 data, but json encode gives error too.

```
public function utf8ize($mixed) {
    if (is_array($mixed)) {
        foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) {
            $mixed[$key] = $this->utf8ize($value);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($mixed)) {
        $enc = mb_detect_encoding($mixed);
        error_log($enc.": ".$mixed." \n\n",3,'x.log');
        //if ($enc != "UTF-8") {
            return utf8_encode($mixed); 
        //}
        //return $mixed;
    }
    return $mixed;
}
```

output of error log for example:

```
ASCII: 2015-02-17 14:35:44

ASCII: Facebook <notification+zrdopdo=ic6f@facebookmail.com>

UTF-8: ... láthatod a fényképeiket ...
```

Do you have any idea, what can I do?

Comment: Are you outputting it to the browser?

Comment: What's your application charset that you've put in the HTML or in the server response?

Comment: `<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">`

Comment: Only it could help me http://stackoverflow.com/a/9713138/1369974