# Using str_replace in combination with ut8_decode

Tags: php, str-replace, utf8-decode

To start I am not that experienced in php yet, so I have this code that I did not write myself.

```
.utf8_decode($var['ciudad']).
```

It returns a value of a city, this is a number, 66170 or 66001.

What I need is, for it not to return the number but the name of the city. So let´s say the return is ´66170´, it should show ´London´ not the number ´66170´.

Now I know I should use str_replace. But here is where I get stuck, the piece of code has utf8_decode in it which messes with my code. (or just confuses me) my idea was more or less like this:

```
$ciudad= .utf8_decode(str_replace('66170 ', 'London',($var['ciudad']).'))
```

Comment: Why do you have dots in front of the `utf8_decode()` function calls?

Comment: I think so yes, tbh i´m a php newbie and I didn´t write the original code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

What You are trying to do is this

```
$ciudad = utf8_decode(str_replace('66170', 'London',$var['ciudad'] ));
```

Removing a dot, a space, some parenthesis and quotes.

**Long Answer**

I recommend use two arrays. First one with all cities number and the second one with all cities name, then use them as `str_replace` parameters. Eg:

```
$citiesCodes = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 66170); 
$citiesNames = Array('New York', 'Santo Domingo', 'La Paz', 'Lima', ... , 'London'); 


$ciudad = utf8_decode(str_replace($citiesCodes, $citiesNames, $var['ciudad'] ));
```

Comment: I'd warn about that way of data definition - it's hard to debug when you'll want to add or remove some cities and shift one array relative to another by mistake... It's better to use an associative array and change `str_replace()` to `strtr()`: `$cities=Array('66170' => 'London', '66001' => 'New York'); $ciudad = strtr($var['ciudad'], $cities);`

Answer (score 0):

Your idea was right. The only thing you've missed is that you first of all need to decode it:

```
$ciudad = str_replace('66170', 'London', utf8_decode($var['ciudad']));
```

If you have many city codes, it's better to use `strtr()`. I've updated my suggestion according your last comment:

```
$cities = Array(
  '66170' => 'London',
  '66001' => 'New York',
  '66002' => 'Beijing',
);

$ciudad = strtr($var['ciudad'], $cities);
```

Comment: I have used the code mentioned above because it made more sense with my limited php knowledge. But I will try your solution tomorrow in the morning for education purposes. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You're welcome! But if the answer above works for you, it seems you don't need to use utf8_decode() at whole... Take a look where it uses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095899/utf8-encoding-problem-with-good-examples It's no reason to do this for simple digits